# pytest django requires db access for a test that doesn't access the db

Tags: python, django, pytest

I've started to move some tests across to using pytest in a django project. However when testing on a simple test, pytest produces an error saying that that test needs access to a db. However the equivalent test in django testrunner used SimpleTestCase which doesn't use the django db.

The original test

```py
class TestHomeView(SimpleTestCase):

    def test_uses_home_template(self):
        response = self.client.get(reverse('home'))
        self.assertTemplateUsed(response, 'pages/home.html')
```

The test in pytest

```py
@pytest.mark.django_db
def test_home_template(client):
    response = client.get(reverse('home'))
    assert 'home.html' in [t.name for t in response.templates]
```

Removing the django_db mark makes the test fail. The only possible use of the db that I can think of is that we are using the session middleware (although we aren't actively using the session in that view). 
Why does pytest think it needs to access the db for this test?

Comment: A `SimpleTestCase` also does raise an exception if a test tries to access the database. This means that if `test_home_template` raises, the `test_uses_home_template` should also raise, assuming the rest of the codebase is identical.

Comment: Thanks for confirming that should be the expectation - it must be something else causing the issue in that case.  I'll keep digging.

Comment: Try reducing the codebase to a [mcve] (remove everything besides the one endpoint `home`). If the error is reproducible, post the code - it may be `pytest-django` behaving differently than `django.test`.